# Jenkins template with count() function - can't test with Jenkins spock

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, spock

I have an existing Jenkins template that uses the count() function on a variable. BUT the groovy definition of count is count(thing). The template works OK and so I think it is quietly using the java definition of count() (which doesn't require a thing to count, just counts everything).

In this sample, the COUNT I added to the script under test, just to prove that count can work. But the actual code looks like the EMTPYCOUNT (which is actually line38).

```
 def build_name_selector = openshift.selector( "bc", "${build_name}" )
 echo "COUNT ${build_name_selector.count('1')} "  //WORKS in test
 echo "EMPTYCOUNT ${build_name_selector.count()} "  // FAILS in test
```

The selector is explained here :
https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin#peer-inside-of-openshift-objects

I have to write a unit test for it. I tried to get a value into build_name_selector with :

```
getPipelineMock("openshift.selector")("bc", _ ) >> ["456","123"]
```

But it errors with :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method count() to invoke from this list:
  public java.lang.Number java.lang.Iterable#count(groovy.lang.Closure)
  public java.lang.Number java.lang.Iterable#count(java.lang.Object)
    at openshift.container.call_closure1$_closure3(container_build.groovy:38)
    at openshift.container.call_closure1$_closure3(container_build.groovy)
    ....
```

So I think I need to create an object in spock that is a selector not a list.
(Please explain your answer like I have no idea about Java, because I don't!)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code defines a Groovy list literal, which at runtime is going to be an `ArrayList` instance. Neither the Java `List` interface nor `ArrayList` have any `count()` method. So your template code - which you did not even bother to show in your question - either uses another variable type which has a `count` method without arguments, or you described the problem incorrectly. Information hiding is not going to give you a better answer than this.

Whether you like it or not, the way to efficiently count the number of total elements in a list is `size()`. The two `count` methods mentioned in your stack trace are Groovy extension methods for lists, defined in class `DefaultGroovyMethods` for `Iterable`s, which lists are one example of. So, whether you like it or not, you have to provide a parameter to each of those two methods, either an `Object` or a `Closure`.

If in your Jenkins environment it works without parameter on list types, another explanation might be that there on the classpath you have some kind of Groovy dynamism like a trait, dynamically adding the method to lists or iterables. I never used the Jenkins API before, so I do not know. If what I just speculated about is the case, you should make sure that your Spock test has the same trait or dynamic method on its classpath as the application code.

Besides, if you insist on counting the total number of elements using `count` instead of simply using `size()` and do not care about efficiency, you can use a trivial closure parameter:

```java
println "EMPTYCOUNT ${build_name_selector.count({ true })}"
```

Comment: I'm not deliberately hiding things, but there is a lot of code to copy/paste that seems mostly irrelevant! I think I have found something that is relevant, in the actual code, the buildnameselector  is a Selector not a list. So edited the question.

Comment: We are talking about a Groovy problem here, not Java. BTW, Groovy is like Java on steroids, 99% a superset of Java. So if you know Groovy, you also know Java. Or did you mean to say that you are a programming beginner in general? As for the MCVE, the article describes is quite nicely. You start with a copy of your full application + test and then delete as much as you can, while still reproducing the problem, until you cannot strip off anything more without no longer being able to reproduce it. You can also start small, then add things, but that is a more theoretical approach, not empirical.

Comment: But, if I don't know Java, I also won't know something that is a superset of Java... Like if I don't know adding up, I probably don't know differential calculus. And it is a Jenkins Spock problem, not a language problem.

Comment: False. Spock requires you to use Groovy, so maybe you should learn some Java/Groovy programming language basics and then Spock basics, before you start using Spock Jenkins, which builds on top of all of them. It is like you are asking: "I have this racing track curve drift problem with my Ferrari. Please tell me how to handle it." Then, when someone asks you to describe the issue in more detail, you reply: "Sorry, I don't know how to drive. Please help me anyway."

Comment: Don't get me wrong, being a beginner is no problem at all, beginners are very welcome here. Being a fool with a tool is a problem, though. The problem is your way to ask questions and the excuses you are using to avoid having to provide enough detail for everyone to at least understand what the heck the problem **is** and ideally be able to reproduce it. You obviously work in IT, looking at your other questions and answers. So you need to know basic techniques to describe a problem in a structured way, otherwise you are lost in your job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but it seems to be working adequately!

```
        def mockSelector = Mock(com.openshift.jenkins.plugins.OpenShiftDSL)
        getPipelineMock("openshift.selector")( _ )  >> mockSelector
        explicitlyMockPipelineStep('count')
        getPipelineMock("count")() >> 1
```